# title attribute in html not resolving special characters

Tags: html, angular

In my code I'm trying to display item title in title attribute. But when item title contains special characters numbers (Eg. `&#174;` for ®) it is not resolving it, And it displays code as it is. Please help me with it.

code

```
<a ng-href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank" title="{{item.title}}"><figure>
                            <img
                                ng-src="{{renderAssetUrl(item.image,{width:'125',height:'125'})}}"
                                alt="{{item.name}}">
                        </figure>
                        <h5 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h5></a>
```

Comment: did you tried `innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding [innerHTML]="item.title" in <a> tag. But nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of $sce which safely inserts the HTML dynamically.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.item = {
    
        title: $sce.trustAsHtml('&#174; hello')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<h5 ng-bind-html="item.title"></h5>
</div>
```